Marching band student copies complicated drum routine perfectly first try
I saw a movie about 10 years ago which followed a marching band, or at least the drumming portion of it, at a school (probably college, maybe high school).
There was one scene which stuck out in my mind: The coach/teacher is demonstrating a very complicated, fast drum routine on the students' first day, showing them this is the sort of drumming they should be able to do at the end of the school year.  The main character (a student, of course) is watching the teacher; the film goes into slow motion and he catches every detail.
Then, after the coach (?) finishes showing the routine, the student picks up his sticks (interjecting into whatever else the coach was going to say) and copies the routine the teacher (?) just demonstrated, doing it flawlessly.
I googled around and found "Drumline" (2002), which looks very similar and may be the movie I'm looking for, but checking the plot summary and YouTube clips I couldn't find anything like the scene I described above.
Is it in fact Drumline that has this scene?  If not, what movie was this?

You are correct, that would be Drumline.  You may not find the exact scene in a trailer or YouTube clip without seeing the entire movie again.
